# Use same file_operation for different files in VFS

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am creating several `dentry` objects in the `securityfs` in a custom kernel module. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
inst->output_file = securityfs_create_file("1",
                               S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP, uprp_dir, NULL,
                               &my_file_ops);
inst->output_file = securityfs_create_file("2",
                               S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP, uprp_dir, NULL,
                               &my_file_ops);
// and so on
```

I have the usual sequence operations implemented for `my_file_ops`. The problem however is that the following function gets called for *all* `dentry` objects:

```
 static int ct_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
```

which then goes on to use:

```
 static void *my_seq_ops_start (struct seq_file *m, loff_t *pos)
```

**The question is, how do I figure out which dentry object the user wants to read (in any of these functions)?** -- meaning I want to output different things for the files `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the VFS calls your `ct_open()` function through the `my_file_ops` structure, it passes back the file that's open, both as a `struct inode *`, and as a `struct file *`.  The `struct file` contains a member `f_dentry`, which is a pointer back to the dentry that was returned by `securityfs_create_file()`.  The `struct dentry` contains the filename.

However, even cleaner is the fact that the 4th argument of `securityfs_create_file()` is for your use.  You can pass in any pointer to whatever internal structure you want, and retrieve it during the open operations from the inode.i_private pointer.  This is normally the "right" level of abstraction, so your file operations don't need to know anything about the filename.

Comment: Thank you very much. I like the second approach better because it's easer to implement. It would be nice of you to recommend the "better" of the two alternatives, just for reference.